# lucene/solr vs mySQL 5.6 LIKE (contains) searches - would moving to solr improve speed?

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

we have a mySQL db with ~ 3M rows and need to do LIKE (contains) searches all the time. meaning, if we search for 'ppl' we need to have 'apple' as one of the results returned. currently, the best we can do is about 2sec for each LIKE query with mySQL.

my question is: would moving the search function to solr (or lucene) speed up the LIKE (contains) type queries over mySQL LIKE queries?

thanks!

ps. I already know that FULLTEXT searches do much better, but those are not "contains" searches.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it would speed queries up. You need to decide how to run those queries, whether to use wildcards: *ppl** or better to tokenize using NGrams and then issue a query with just ppl.

But it will definitively be faster, as that is lucene/solr's main functionality.

Comment: thanks for the response! I will try either solr or sphinx and see if it helps us.